# Returning values from an object method

Tags: javascript, object, methods

This is a piece of code from a [github repo](https://github.com/fullstacktraining/introduction-to-typescript/blob/master/section01/code/arrow.js) I am trying to understand

```js
const quotient = {
  numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  results: [ ],
  divideFn: function (divisor) {
    return this.numbers.map(function (divident) {
      if (divident % divisor === 0) {
        return this.results.push(divident);
      }
    });
  },
};
```

#### Problem statement:

1. The first problem is the value of "this" in the callback function inside the map, which can be solved using arrow function syntax.
2. figuring out the values that are returned from this procedure, because the code actually pushes the values to an empty array in the main object.
   So checking in the debugger, returned values are not what I expect

[image: Returned values of the "divideFn" method]

3. If calling the "divideFn" more than once, results are incorrect, like:

```js
quotient.divideFn(3)
const byThree = quotient.results

quotient.divideFn(2)
const byTwo = quotient.results
```

The values from the previous method call is still available in the results array

Things I tried:

I added a condition in the method to solve this

```js
const quotient = {
  numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  results: [ ],
  divideFn (divisor) {
    
    **if (this.results.length !== 0) this.results = []**
      this.numbers.map( divident => {
      if (divident % divisor === 0) {
        this.results.push(divident);
      }
    });
  },
};
```

But in terms of memory efficiency, if the operation involves large number of values, the results array holds variables until next invocation.

I'd appreciate if you explain the correct way of constructing this object and its method

Comment: That's a misuse of `.map()`! A call to the `.map()` method ***always*** produces a new array. The content of the array is determined based on the original array with each element transformed by the mapping function `[1, 2, 3].map(f)` produces `[f(1), f(2), f(3)]`. Since you have an `if` some times you never return anything. When you do, the return value is the return value of `this.results.push(divident);` - where the `.push()` method just returns the new array length. Since it's *not* doing a mapping operation, `.forEach` or a normal loop is more approriate. Alternatively, `.filter()`.

Comment: byThree and byTwo refer the SAME array object.

Comment: @Florent the whole object approach here is extremely strange. You need to call a method, which then mutates a property and you are expected to read that mutated property. Yet, each successive call re-uses the same `result` array anyway accumulating values without being able to meaningfully distinguish between them. It's like the worst parts of using globals put in an object form. I suppose you could liken the usafge to stateful regex objects but at least those are easier to re-set or interrogate. I'm not sure what purpose the code serves overall as it's a bad example of many things.